# Trail Render not become visible during game play

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was working on simple 2d game and in that at player end, I want to attach trail effect. So I have added trail renderer component by creating child empty gameobject.

Also I have set proper trail rendering order as well. Here are more details with images so please check these:
[image]

Actual trail get drawn but not visible on game or in scene area.

Here is the component values those I set for trail renderer:
[image]

Now I hope you got my point so please share your suggestion regarding this. 
Thank you for giving time for this question :)

Trail Renderer more details:
[image]

Player more details:
[image]

Gameplay more details:
[image]

Actually game play remain at same location, just I am dragging player ball through mouse so no rotation get included.

Still if you need more information then you can ask for that I will provide those as fast as possible.

Comment: can you show use the hierchy? Is this trail attached to another gameobject? if so can we see that objects transform?

Comment: I have shown more details in this - actual player is ball object and trail attached to it - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GqltrT9tfKOtVlNvcFDh0a56HA6HzFVy

Comment: unfortunately, that screenshot still doesnt show what all I asked for, I see your trail is a child of player, and a child of gameplay.  What is the rotation of those 2 objects?  Also, in the future please edit your question and include the screenshots there.

Comment: Please check updated question...

Comment: Not really sure, can you reproduce this same issue with a fresh project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem after doing some tries. Here I am posting an answer so this become useful to other members.

I require to set Material type to **Mobile/Particles** then after it become visible within game play. Though sorting order related setting is necessary that I was did before. But material related settings I don't knew before.

[image]